# Smalltalk - iterate over a dict array with conditions

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I'm working on a Smalltalk small method, I want this method to iterate over a dictionary array and to return True or False depend on the conditions.

The dictionary array is an instance variable, name dictArray.

It looks like: `[{'name': toto, 'age': 12}, {'name': tata, 'age': 25}]`

So I want to iterate over dictArray and verify for each item the name and the age. If it matches I return true else false and the end of the iteration.

In python it should look like:

```
for item in dictArray:
    if item['name'] == aName and item['age'] == aAge:
        return True
return False
```

I can't find documentation with this special case (array iteration + condition + return)

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To test whether a Collection contains an element that matches a condition, use `anySatisfy:`. It answers true iff there is a matching element.

```
dictArray anySatisfy: [:each | (each at: 'name') = aName and: [(each at: 'age') = anAge]]
```

Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual-base/html_node/Iterable_002denumeration.html

The way described above is the preferred way to write it. The following is only for explanation how it relates to your Python code example.

`anySatisfy:` can be implemented in terms of `do:`

```
anySatisfy: aBlock
   self do: [:each | (aBlock value: each) ifTrue: [^ true]].
   ^ false
```

Or spelled out with your condition:

```
dictArray do:
   [:each |
   ((each at: 'name') = aName and: [(each at: 'age') = anAge])
      ifTrue: [^ true]].
^ false
```

This is the equivalent of your Python code.

Comment: Your first example is "the Smalltalk way" (elegant and no ^ is needed).  I think you should stress that this is the preferred way.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JayK, you're helping a lot !!
Before I accept your answer, can you please show how can I add and new "and" condition ? For exemple If I want to do:      if item['name'] == aName and item['age'] == aAge and item['something'] == aSomething:

Comment: @MalkovitchJohn In the first example you just add another `and: [boolean]`.  However, too many conditions usually indicate some flaw in the design.

Comment: @tukan I edited the answer as you suggested. Thank you.